# Cordova: Reading directories and files from SD-Card

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I'm trying to read directories and files from a folder on the external SD-Card on Android. `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` is returning `file:///storage/emulated/0/` which is not the path of the SD-Card. 
Using `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails()` I got the root path of my SD-Card but if I try to read it, it returns `FileError code: 5`.

Cordova Version: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) Android-API Level: 22

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(data) {                 
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(data[0].filePath + "/", 
  $scope.onFSSuccess, $scope.onError);
}, console.log);
```

$scope.onError is triggered returning error 5.

```
this.onError = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Function which should create reader of SD-Card folder.

```
this.onFSSuccess = function(fileSystem) {
  fs = fileSystem;
  var directoryReader = fileSystem.createReader();
  directoryReader.localURL = directoryReader.localURL + $scope.dirPath;
  $scope.directoryReaderPath = directoryReader.localURL;
  directoryReader.readEntries($scope.readerSuccess, $scope.onError);
}
```

**NOTE: i added the following lines to the config.xml**

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Update: I tried using an absolute path. `file:///storage/sdcard/0/`
Still not working.